# How to parse text into json in express sever using bodyParser?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, express, body-parser

I have an express server which is acting as an API, main.ts (this has the code to up the server) looks somewhat like this

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/plain" }));
app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(8080, () => {});
```

and the routes object has a GET definition as :-

```
routes.get('/myObject', (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    console.log(request.body); // Output : {}
});
```

I have another server from where I send a request but the request body is not getting parsed as it should

The XHR I'm sending from the second server is :-

```
    const request: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/myObject");
    request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    request.onload = () => {
        console.log(request.status);
    };
    request.onerror = (err) => {
        console.log(request.status);
    }
    request.send(JSON.stringify({ "key": "value" }));
```

But on my express server, { "key": "value" } is not appearing only {} is coming?

Any idea what is wrong here?

Also if I do get `"{\"key\":\"value\"}"` in the express server can I implicitly convert it to a JSON object which can be sent as request.body?

Answer (score 1):

Change the method to POST  instead of GET and give it a try.
Responses for GET´s have their body set to null.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Using POST works. But I'm curious as of why it doesn't work with get when I send an XHR and does via Postman? 
When I sent a request with postman, it recognized the request body.